# How to fix this collection view and arrays issue?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I am using Swift 3. I have set up a collectionView with 7 sections - when user taps a cell(button) a specific sound will play from an array of sounds.

So how do I split up the sections in the collectionView to match a specific array of sounds?

for instance

1) sounds in soundArray1 will play when users tap cells(buttons) in section 1 of collectionView

2) sounds in soundArray2 will play when users tap cells(buttons) in section 2 of collectionView

3) sounds in soundArray3 will play when users tap cells(buttons) in section 3 of collectionView

all the way up to section 7.

Here is the current code when user taps cellButton

```
@IBAction func cellButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
let sound =  (sender as! UIButton).tag
self.setupAudioPlayer(file: Sounds[sound] as NSString, type: ".m4a")
self.soundPlayer.play()}
```

where Sounds is array 1 of sound files. However this array of sound files is playing across all sections of the `collectionView` right now. I can't work out how to split each array of sounds to match each section in the `collectionView`.

Comment: Use an Array of sound arrays and use the section number to extract the correct sound array and cell number to get the correct sound from that array?

Comment: Also how are you setting the tag of the UIButton?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an array of arrays for your sounds:

```
let allSounds = [soundArray1, soundArray2, soundArray3]
```

where each element in the array represents the section of the collectionView.

To get the sound that is the first element in section 0, you would go:

```
let soundArray = allSounds[0]  // Get section 0
let sound = soundArray[0] // Get sound at index 0
```

Or to get the sound at index 7 in section 2, you would go:

```
let soundArray = allSounds[2]  // Get section 2
let sound = soundArray[6] // Get sound at index 7
```

Comment: His button's tag will have to represent both indexPath.section and indexPath.row tho

Comment: Assuming there are the same number of buttons in each section, it would be fairly easy to work out using integer math: 

`tag % no-of-items-in-section` & `tag / no-of-items-in-section`

Comment: However, a much better method would be to either use `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` instead of buttons, or blocks within the cell to callback to the controller

Comment: Tendai, That would be an assumption. Which is why we have comments to ask OP for clarification. This answer is pretty much the same approach I had in mind (See my earlier comment on question) but I needed clarification so I left a comment instead. (Not implying that you did something wrong, Fastest gun in the west wins ;) )

Comment: Yup using tablview delegates is better but again, we don't know if he has multiple buttons or other controls in the cell to perform different operations so the didSelectCell might not be a valid choice for him. So yup, again, comment. This is merely helping you along on how SO works, since you appear to be a new user. Welcome aboard :)

Comment: :) Thanks, sadly I can't leave comments because I dont have enough reputation yet!

Comment: let soundArray = allSounds[0]
            let sound = soundArray[0]
          self.setupAudioPlayer(file: [soundArray] as NSString, type: ".m4a")
        
       
        
        
       self.soundPlayer.play()

Comment: something like the above? Thanks for the help by the way

Comment: @IBAction func cellButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {let soundArray = allSounds[0] let sound = soundArray[0] self.setupAudioPlayer(file: [soundArray] as NSString, type: ".m4a") self.soundPlayer.play()}

Comment: or where exactly do I place your code above? Within my button action code or elsewhere?